# Time complexity of $T(n)= 2T(\left\lfloor\sqrt n\right\rfloor) + \log^3(n)$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I have to solve the time complexity of the above recurrence. My steps so far are:

let $n= 2^m$

$T(2^m)= 2T(2^{m/2})+ \log^3(2^m)$

$S(m)= T(2^m)$

$S(m)= 2S(m/2)+ \log^3(2^m)$

This solves to $S(m)= \Theta(m \log(m))$

This means for T:

$T(n)= \Theta(\log(n)*\log\log(n))$

I'm not so sure about this. Could you help me?

Comment: I believe $S(m) = \Theta(m^3)$. See [this WA evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+s%28m%29+%3D+2*s%28m%2F2%29+%2B+%28log%282%5Em%29%29%5E3)

Comment: Oh yes of course. So, then $T(n)= \Theta(\log^3(n))$?

Comment: Exactly. $T(n) = \frac{4}{3} \ln^3(n)$ would solve $T(n) = 2T\left(\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor \right) + \ln^3(n)$. I'm not sure how much the floor will affect the solution though.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When you have
$$
S(m)=2S\left(\frac m2\right)+\log^3(2^m)=m^3\underbrace{\log^3(2)}_{k}+2S\left(\frac m2\right)
$$

You can substitute couple more steps to see the pattern:
$$
S(m)=km^3+2S(m/2)=km^3+2k\left(\frac m2\right)^3+4S(m/4)=\\km^3+2k\left(\frac m2\right)^3+4k\left(\frac m4\right)^3+8S(m/8)=\ldots=
km^3\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{4^2}+\ldots\right)}_{\log m\text{ terms}}
$$

We can see that the coefficient is between $1$ and $\sum_0^\infty4^{-n}=4/3$. In other words, it is constant. Thus, $S(m)=\Theta(m^3)$

Comment: Thank you. But the second part can alternatively be done with the master theorem, right? Of course I would not get the coefficient in that way, but i would still be able to get the asymptotic complexity?!